# select positions of value of string or int

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to select the positions of some value and print the parts of that value by position in java when I'm working on android app.
for example if I have some number four-digit, 4375 if I select the 3rd one system will print 7, 4th one system will print 5..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily select the portion of a string with String.substring() methods. 
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html for more help.

Hence, you could simply convert the digit to String and then use the substring() method get the part you want.

I will just provide my solution as a suggestion:

```
    private String getSubDigit(int value, int postion){
        // you probably should check if the value is correct and ready to be processed.
        if(Check(value)) {
           String temp = "" + value;
           return temp.substring(position,position+1);
        }else{
           return "";
        }


    }
```

Comment: yes, thank you I tried I need only String string1,string2;
string1="4512";
string2=string1.substring(0);
the solution= 4

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive it like this

```
int values = 4375;
String mValue = String.valuOf(values);
Char mChar = mValue.chatAt(int index);

int selectedValue = Character.getNumericValue(mChar);
```